# How to build Qt Remote Object based project using Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, qt5

How can I use Qt Remote Object with Cmake? Is there a variable to be set in Cmake to use repc?

Comment: [This bug report][1] hints that the remote object related cmake integration is not yet documented. Seems like there is a cmake function `qt5_generate_repc ()` somewhere.

  [1]: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-82461

Comment: I couldn't find any relevant examples of qt remote object with Cmake. Is qt remote object obselete? Could anyone suggest any rpc api in C++ that integrates well with Cmake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cmake macros have been there for a long time, but the documentation has lagged behind.  See [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtremoteobjects-cmake-qt5-generate-repc.html) for the recently added documentation.

It boils down to adding the Qt Remote Objects module

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core RemoteObjects REQUIRED)
```

then telling cmake to run repc to autogenerate the code from any .rep files you want to use

```
qt5_generate_repc(<SOURCES> rep_file output_type) # output_type SOURCE or REPLICA
```

add making sure Remote Objects is included in the linkage

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt5::Core Qt5::RemoteObjects)
```